# How can i implement the search nearby functionality in android?

Tags: android, search, geolocation, location, google-api

I am developing a classified app in which user can post and find others ads,

For finding functionality of ads, I need to implement search nearby functionality. what should be my possible approach?

I have the latitude and longitude of users who has posted the ad.

What are the possibilities to implement the same in android.

Comment: Yes, if you have latitude/longitude of advertisements/posts, you can implement nearest functionality straight way by finding distance between current lat/long and post's lat/long.

Comment: @PareshMayani:Thank you for replying. I am a beginner here, if you can give me few links of examples with same kind of functionality, it will be easier for me to implement the same for learning purpose.

Comment: Do R&D on what I said in previous comment!